TypeError: finance_tracker.create_widgets.<locals>.<lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'col'
I am getting an error in the following code
class finance_tracker:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.geometry("1000x550")
        self.root.resizable(False, False)
        self.root.title('Personal Finance Tracker')
        self.root.iconbitmap(r'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\SD1_Courseworks\COURSEWORK_03\tracker_icon.ico')
        self.FILE_PATH = 'transaction.json'
        self.transactions = self.load_transaction()
        self.create_widgets()
        self.max_id = max(
            transaction['id'] for category in self.transactions.values() for transaction in
            category) if self.transactions else 0
        self.search_transactions()

    def create_widgets(self):

        # create label
        display_title = tk.Label(self.root, text="Manage Your Transactions Here!",
                                 anchor="center", font=TITLE_FONT_STYLE, bg=BLUE_GRAY)
        display_title.pack()

        # Add Some style
        style = ttk.Style()

        # pick a theme
        style.theme_use('clam')  # themes - defaults, alt, clam, vista

        # configure our treeview colors
        style.configure('Treeview',
                        background='White',
                        foreground='Black',
                        rowheight=25,
                        fieldbackground=ASH_GRAY)
        # change selected color
        style.map('Treeview',
                  background=[('selected', BUTTERSCOTCH_ORANGE)])

        # create treeview frame
        tree_frame = tk.Frame(self.root)
        tree_frame.configure(bg=BLUE_GRAY)
        tree_frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True, pady=10)

        # create treeview scroll bar
        tree_scroll = tk.Scrollbar(tree_frame)
        tree_scroll.configure(bg=BLUE_GRAY, relief=tk.FLAT)
        tree_scroll.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

        # create the tree view
        self.my_tree = ttk.Treeview(tree_frame, yscrollcommand=tree_scroll.set, selectmode=tk.EXTENDED)
        self.my_tree.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, padx=10)

        # defining columns
        self.my_tree['columns'] = (
            'Transaction Type', 'Transaction Category', 'Transaction Amount', 'Transaction Date', 'Transaction ID')

        # configure scroll bars
        tree_scroll.configure(command=self.my_tree.yview)

        # format columns
        self.my_tree.column('#0', width=0, stretch=NO)
        for col in self.my_tree['columns']:
            self.my_tree.column(col, anchor=tk.CENTER, width=120)

        # create headings
        self.my_tree.heading('#0', text='', anchor=tk.W)
        for col in self.my_tree['columns']:
            self.my_tree.heading(col, text=col, anchor=tk.CENTER,
                                 command=lambda col: self.sort_by_column(self.my_tree, col, False))

        # create transaction type based striped row tags
        self.my_tree.tag_configure('income_row', background=ROBIN_EGG_BLUE)
        self.my_tree.tag_configure('expense_row', background=VERDIGRIS_BLUE)

        # adding data to the screen
        self.count = 0
        for item in self.transactions.keys():
            for record in self.transactions.get(item):
                if record['type'] == 'Income':
                    self.my_tree.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=self.count, text='',
                                        values=(
                                        record['type'], item, f'{record['amount']:,.2f}', record['date'], record['id']),
                                        tags=('income_row',))
                elif record['type'] == 'Expense':
                    self.my_tree.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=self.count, text='',
                                        values=(
                                        record['type'], item, f'{record['amount']:,.2f}', record['date'], record['id']),
                                        tags=('expense_row',))
                self.count += 1  # increment counter
    def sort_by_column(self, tree, col, reverse):
        for row in tree.get_children():
            data = (tree.set(row, col), row)
            data.sort(reverse=reverse)

            for index in range(len(data)):
                val, row = data[index]
                tree.move(row, '', index)

            tree.heading(col, command=lambda c=col: self.sort_by_column(tree, c, not reverse))

I tried changing the code by changing c=col. But it did not worked

As the error in title says, the callback for the command option of Treeview.heading() expect no argument, so the lambda in the following code inside create_widgets():
def create_widgets(self):
    ...
    for col in self.my_tree['columns']:
        self.my_tree.heading(col, text=col, anchor=tk.CENTER,
                             command=lambda col: self.sort_by_column(self.my_tree, col, False))
    ...

should be changed to:
def create_widgets(self):
    ...
    for col in self.my_tree['columns']:
        self.my_tree.heading(col, text=col, anchor=tk.CENTER,
                             # set default value to col argument
                             command=lambda col=col: self.sort_by_column(self.my_tree, col, False))
    ...

